# How to copy files to another document library with new folder in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer-workflow

We have two document libraries(suppose TestLib1 & TestLib2), when a new file added to TestLib1 it required automatically copied to TestLib2 with new folder and add item under that folder using SharePoint Designer workflow 2013.

I am able to create a folder in TestLib2 but can't move the item to the newly created folder.
Kindly provide workaround to get the requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please provide a solution to get the requirement done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please someone give the insights on the above.

Comment: can someone provide the solution for the above.